# How do I move between lines in an IPython terminal on a Mac?

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, ipython

Occasionally I'll write a 10 or 20-line function in IPython and notice after I try to execute it that I made a few typos.  The commands <kbd>Ctrl+P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+N</kbd> just take me to previous commands rather than lines, meaning that I currently have to retype the entire function to correct a few typos.  Obviously this is time consuming.

Is there a built-in IPython command that will let me navigate across lines in a single long command?  The official IPython documentation has not been particularly helpful.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the `%edit` or `%ed` commands to enter into your default editor and have much more flexibility.